# CMD-Z reopens last tab instead of undoing

Tags: safari

This is unbelievably annoying, since when I code online, there is no means of undoing, and thus retrieving the text I deleted.

Answer (score 26):

Most online text editors which support keyboard shortcuts (like the Stack Exchange editor right here!) support ⌃Z (ctrl-Z) for undo too, which won't cause any system functions to be fired.

If you want to use ⌘Z, you can remap the Undo Close Tab function off ⌘Z to something else using System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts. Set Application to Safari.app, Menu Title to Undo Close Tab and Keyboard Shortcut to something other than ⌘Z.

[image]

Comment: Specifically on SE, Cmd/Z will will undo the last text operation if you have a text area currently selected, otherwise will restore a closed tab.

Comment: ON Ventura, go to System Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts... → App Shortcuts then press the plus button and type in the menu title `Undo Close Tab` then remap the key.

Comment: Geez, why does this exist?! Thanks for the answer. Of note is that in Ventura I can't find the "Undo Close Tab" option in any of the menus, so this answer is really needed just to find the command to override!

Comment: What you can find is "Reopen Last Closed Tab" in the History menu, which is correctly mapped to command+shift+t. That's the one people should keep!

Answer (score 3):

If you use a language other than English and the [proposed solution by grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297228/cmd-z-reopens-last-tab-instead-of-undoing/297229#297229) doesn't work, specify in System Preferences > Keyboard the equivalent to "Undo Close Tab" in your language.

For example, if Safari's interface language is Russian, open a tab, close it, select the Edit menu:

[image: screenshot of location menu title 'Undo Close Tab' in Edit].

and use the text next to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (that is, 'Отменить закрытие вкладки') instead of "Undo Close Tab".